# How to seperate woocommerce login and register page separate?

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

I want to have separate woocommerce login and register pages. I want to have a link on login page for redirection to register page. Kindly help me in this issue.
Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

#### Woocommerce Login / Signup Lite

With this free Sign Up/ Login plugin, you can easily create a sign-up and login process for your e-commerce site. This WordPress plugin gives you three simple shortcodes that you can paste on your site code to create a simple Signup/Login system for your website.

You can separate your login/registration page with shortcode. Also, there is a pop-up feature.
You can either create Sign Up/ Login Widgets or Pages.

With this plugins, you get short codes for:

1. **Short code for login form** – `[lsphe-login-form]`
2. **Short code for signup form** – `[lsphe-signup-form]`
3. **Shortcode for both login and register form** – `[lsphe-header]`

After creating pages with those shortcodes just set your login and registration menu. Then you will get an individual page to login or register.